# Trying to make my player shoot by touching any part of the screen

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

I am trying to make my player shoot by touching the screen, I already done that, the only problem is that it just shoots if I touch the player, but what I want is to be able to shoot by touching any part of the screen, any suggestions? I would appreciate it.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent;
import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.system.TouchscreenType;

public class spaceShooter extends MovieClip {

    public var mcPlayer:MovieClip;
    private var theAcc:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
    private var aMissileArray:Array;


    public function spaceShooter() {
        // constructor code

        ///////////////////////////
        ///////Missile Array///////
        ///////////////////////////
        aMissileArray = new Array();


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////Touch-Tap Missile///////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onTouch);


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////Player Movement Accelerometer///////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop)

        theAcc.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, onAcc);

        function onAcc(e:AccelerometerEvent):void{
        mcPlayer.x -= (e.accelerationX * 65);
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////Fire Missile onTouch/////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        function onTouch(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            ////////////////
            //fire missile//
            ////////////////
            fireMissile();
        }

        function fireMissile():void
        {
            //////////////////////
            //create new missile//
            //////////////////////
            var newMissile:mcMissile = new mcMissile();
            ///////////////////////////////////
            //add missile object to the stage//
            ///////////////////////////////////
            stage.addChild(newMissile);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //position our missile object on top of player//
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            newMissile.x = mcPlayer.x;
            newMissile.y = mcPlayer.y;
            /////////////////////////////
            //add our new missile array//
            /////////////////////////////
            aMissileArray.push(newMissile);
            trace(aMissileArray.length);
        }

    }

    private function gameLoop(e:Event):void{
        clampPlayerToStage();
    }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //If our player is to the Left of The Stage//
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
    private function clampPlayerToStage():void{
        if(mcPlayer.x < mcPlayer.width/2)
        {
            mcPlayer.x = mcPlayer.width/2;
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        //If our Player is to the Right of the Stage//
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(mcPlayer.x > stage.stageWidth - (mcPlayer.width/2))
        {
            mcPlayer.x = stage.stageWidth - (mcPlayer.width/2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you subscribe the wrong object for TOUCH_TAP event. The display object relevant to this class contains player's graphics and thus touchable/clickable only where its graphics is present. You either need to have a big interactive object here along with the player, or just transparent graphics. Or, maybe this: **stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onTouch);**

Comment: thank you, I did what you said, about the stage.addEventListener and it worked, I really appreciated it,